# Rescue option issue on ubuntu 20.4

Tags: 20.04, vmware

I am trying to migrate my ubuntu server for my client.

I already import the disks but not being able to boot ubuntu to rescue mode.

Please find attached screenshot when typing (esc)  or any other related key to grub menu.

[image]

Kindly advise.

Comment: Your question is missing the screenshot.

Comment: To clarify, you have copied the VMware disk images of your client’s server to a new VMware installation, and you cannot boot the machine at all, so you are trying to enter “Rescue Mode”. Is this correct? 

Comment: Hello, There is no such version of Ubuntu as 20.4